# car radio sd doesn't work when formated from ubuntu

Tags: file-format, sd-card

My radio car reads SD card only when formated from windows. When I format it from ubuntu it says "no file", althought in the computer (both from windows and ubuntu) I can see their contents. Is there a way to do it from ubuntu exactly like windows do it?

Comment: What format did you format it to?

Answer (score 1):

There are different kinds of file systems: Not every device(/operating system) can read all the file system. Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Supporting_operating_systems) for a full list of file systems. There you can compare which device (or operating system) can handle which which file system.

Because your car radio has no operating system (in that sense of Windows, Linux, …) you should select a file system which is widely used: FAT32, NTFS.

Comment: Hy. Tried Fat32, Fat16 ("mkdosfs -F 32 -v (device name)") and NTFS (with disk utility) from ubuntu without succes. From windows Fat(default); the other options are FAT32, NTFS and xFAT; 32k allocation unit size is the one that works

Comment: You could try formatting the sd with gparted. It is available in the repositoryies.

Comment: No way with gparted. Car radio saying the same: "no file". But discovered something in disk utility, the 'type of partition' when formated from windows is 'FAT16 (0x06)', 'type: FAT (16 bit version)'. Tried format the type of partition with disk utility and format FAT16 with gparted, wich shows the same properties in disk utility, without luck. Any ideas?